# SQL Query to return most recent row WITH an additional filter

Tags: mysql, sql

Very much stuck with a certain query I'm trying to run.

Here's the table structure -

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| caseID | status   | update | 
+--------+----------+--------+
     1       New      3-4-2013
     1       Open     3-5-2013
     2       New      3-5-2013
     3       Closed   3-5-2013
```

I want my query return the most recent row and then only display rows where status = 'New', i.e. in the sample data only the row caseID = 2 should be returned.

I have this query

`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY update DESC) AS foo GROUP BY caseID`

That query returns the most recent row for each caseID. Now I'm struck with the part of just displaying where status = 'New'.

I tried this and got an #1064 SQL error

```
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY update DESC) AS foo GROUP BY caseID WHERE status = 'New'
```

I tried this and it returns all rows where status='New' even if they are not the most recent. Which is not what I want.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY update DESC) AS foo WHERE status = 'New' GROUP BY caseID
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific RDBMS you're using.

Comment: `select caseId, status, max('update') as 'update' from table where status = 'New'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the date of the most recent row using `group by`, then `join` and filter:

```
select s.*
from structure s join
     (select caseId, max(update) as maxupdate
      from structure s
      group by caseid
     ) ss
     on s.caseId = ss.caseId and s.update = ss.maxupdate
where s.status = 'New';
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
select * from data
  join (select caseId, max(`update`) as 
           `update` from data 
           where status = 'New' 
           group by caseId) as filter
     on filter.caseId = data.caseId and filter.`update` = data.`update`
where data.status = 'New'
  group by data.caseId;
```

Basically, you're joining the table to itself, but the inner join is identifying the most recent record that you're trying to retrieve.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/631a1/4)